# Laptop Hdd spins down and up making click noise when screen is off

Tags: hard-drive

My hard drive produces a clicking sound whenever the screen is off. The hard drive spins down then spins up during which makes a click sound. This sound doesn't come when connected to charger or when the screen is on. Hdd sleep time is set to 30 min still this sound comes. Laptop:- asus r558uq, hdd:-Seagate.
OS:-win 10.
Please help. 
Here is the link of the sound i have recorded https://youtu.be/ryBG7y7lino?
Now it clicks almost every 2seconds the video is 1 week old.

Comment: Reinstall all display drivers. If this problem persists, check your hardware for any damage. Does your device experience high temperature conditions such as prolonged exposure to sunlight or tight spaces with little ventilation?

Comment: A clicking sound from a HDD is almost always the sound of a failing disk. Back up all your files now.

Comment: @Xavierjazz The clicking sound only comes when screen is off and on battery and not when screen is off while connected to charger.

Comment: @Shankensteinium the laptop is well ventilated and under room temperature. I will try reinstalling the drivers and update.

Comment: I sent it to service centre and got it replaced now the sound is little better. the sound was of parking of head I guess happens in this too but with lesser noise and frequency

Comment: I have the same issue, I think it's got to do with some power saving setting, I think it's trying to sleep then gets woken up again etc Could be some software that tried to tweak something?